# spring boot wants me to start server because I have servlet on classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

today I faced following problem:

One of my core dependencies unfortunately pulls servlet.api to my classpath. Because of this, my spring-boot thinks I'm automatically a server, while I'm a desktop app, and does not want to start without some factories needed to web.

This is what it says:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
```

Unfortunately I can't get rid of this dependency, and for them to fix their transitive dependencies will probably take some time.

Is there any hack to walk around this?

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-non-web-application

Comment: Assuming you're using Maven, can't you exclude  the dependency in your `pom.xml` ? If not, you'll have to set the `setWebApplicationType` on your `SpringApplication` as mentionned in the URL posted by JB Nizet.

Comment: Can you post here your pom.xml content? @Dreando

Comment: Brajesh - I can't post the code here.
Thoomas - unfortunately when I exlude things, then this library does not work.
JBNizet - seems like you're right, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Spring boot 2.x, you can disable the web application by setting the `spring.main.web-application-type` property to `none`:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

If you're using Spring boot 1.x, you could set the `spring.main.web-environment` property:

```
spring.main.web-environment=false
```

The reason this changed is because Spring boot 2.x can now be configured to be either reactive, servlet-based or none, while in Spring boot 1.x it was either servlet-based or none (so it could be just a boolean).

---

Alternatively, you can also use a custom `SpringApplication` instance as mentioned by [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-non-web-application) (and in the comments):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
        .web(WebApplicationType.NONE) // Use this for Spring boot 2.x
        .web(false) // Use this for Spring boot 1.x
        .run(args);
}
```

> Not all Spring applications have to be web applications (or web services). If you want to execute some code in a `main` method but also bootstrap a Spring application to set up the infrastructure to use, you can use the `SpringApplication` features of Spring Boot. A `SpringApplication` changes its `ApplicationContext` class, depending on whether it thinks it needs a web application or not. The first thing you can do to help it is to leave server-related dependencies (e.g. servlet API) off the classpath. If you cannot do that (for example, you run two applications from the same code base) then you can explicitly call `setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE)` on your `SpringApplication` instance or set the `applicationContextClass` property (through the Java API or with external properties).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some required JAR file to run it as web application. Please make sure to that you have included **spring-boot-starter-web.jar** file. 
If we are using maven, do it as follows.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: He doesn't want to start a web server.